# Datenum Matlab:

Tags: matlab

In my code I have looped different text files to get the time elapsed and the temperature. And then plot temperature and time
The text file has data like this

```
Date; Time; Temp °C
06.12.2011; 10:35:11;-24.13
06.12.2011; 10:36:34;-24.00
06.12.2011; 10:37:56;-23.88
.
.
.
.

header=fgetl(fid);
data=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter',';');
fclose(fid);
data=data{:};
day=data(1:3:end);
hour=data(2:3:end);
temp=str2double(data(3:3:end));
time=cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%s %s',day{strcmpi(hour,x)},x),hour,'uniformoutput',0);
timen=datenum(time,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
seconds=timen*86400/60;
plot(seconds-seconds(1),temp);
xlabel('Time(mins)');
ylabel('Temp °C');
```

But now when the time elapsed is greater than 24 hrs in the text files(the temperature reading last for more than one day), the datenum gives an error

```
Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

Any suggestions why this is happening, I tried using the same in command line it works fine there

Comment: It seems like the date string in one of the entries in the `time` variable does not match the `dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS` format. For example, you get the same error for `datenum('12.10.2010 A:B:C', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datenum` did not fail to me when receiving values for hour greater than 24. For example:

```
>> time = '06.12.2011 53:31:11';
>> timen=datenum(time,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
>> datestr(timen,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS')

ans =

08.12.2011 05:31:11
```

However, while trying to run your code, I did get the same error but in the cases when there were two observations with the same time stamp. That happens because the line:

```
time=cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%s %s',day{strcmpi(hour,x)},x),hour,'uniformoutput',0);
```

will concatenate multiple values of `day` and one value of `hour` generating an invalid time string such as `'07.12.2011 07.12.201110:36:11 '`

Since it looks like you want one value of `time` per observation (as opposed to one per `unique(hour)`), I suggest calculating `time` as

```
time = strcat(day,{' '},hour)
```